# Datetimepicker text value changes but value doesn't give the expected value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datetimepicker

I have created a class change the appearance of the calander.
The class is based on these previous stackoverflow questions:

Source1: [Setting calendar size when overriding DateTimePicker to add week numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559074/setting-calendar-size-when-overriding-datetimepicker-to-add-week-numbers)

Source2: [Increase Font Size of DateTimePicker Calender in Win7 Aero Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16031370/increase-font-size-of-datetimepicker-calender-in-win7-aero-theme)

This is the class:

```
class DateTimePickerImpl : DateTimePicker
{
    private const int McmFirst = 0x1000;
    private const int McmGetminreqrect = (McmFirst + 9);
    private const int McsWeeknumbers = 0x4;
    private const int DtmFirst = 0x1000;
    private const int DtmGetmonthcal = (DtmFirst + 8);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr handleToWindow, int offsetToValueToGet);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr h, int index, int value);
    [DllImport("uxtheme.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string appname, string idlist);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int param, int data);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr h);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr h, int msg, int param, ref Rectangle data);
    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int MoveWindow(IntPtr h, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);

    protected override void OnDropDown(EventArgs e)
    {
        CalendarFont = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        const int offsetToGetWindowsStyles = (-16);

        IntPtr pointerToCalenderWindow = SendMessage(Handle, DtmGetmonthcal, 0, 0);
        SetWindowTheme(pointerToCalenderWindow, "", "");
        int styleForWindow = GetWindowLong(pointerToCalenderWindow, offsetToGetWindowsStyles);

        styleForWindow = styleForWindow | McsWeeknumbers;

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        SendMessage(pointerToCalenderWindow, McmGetminreqrect, 0, ref rect);

        rect.Width = rect.Width + 30;
        rect.Height = rect.Height + 10;

        SetWindowLong(pointerToCalenderWindow, offsetToGetWindowsStyles, styleForWindow);

        MoveWindow(pointerToCalenderWindow, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, true);

        IntPtr parentWindow = GetParent(pointerToCalenderWindow);
        MoveWindow(parentWindow, 0, 0, rect.Width, rect.Height, true);

        base.OnDropDown(e);
    }
}
```

Afther implementing this class the visible text of the datetimepicker changes to whatever you choose. But when using `dateTimePickerImpl.Value` it always returns the it began with (the time the datetimpicker loaded). I already found out by adding a method to the `ValueChanged` event that this event never happens. I found some similar problems online but these were all solved by setting the `checked` property of the datetimepicker to true. In my case the `checked` property is already true.

What did i do to break the datetimepicker?

Comment: I tested and it works properly for me.

Comment: It works on my Windows7 machine. The `ValueChanged` event fires. The `Value` value is correct. Do you have more than one calendar control on your form? If so, are you certain you're testing the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to create the datetime picker manually instead of dragging it from the toolbox into the designer.

```
DateTimePickerImpl dtp = new DateTimePickerImpl();
dtp.Location = new Point(3, 254);
dtp.Name = "dtp";
dtp.Size = new Size(271, 26);
dtp.TabIndex = 25;
panel1.Controls.Add(dtp);
```